# How to have a PC's monitor input switch

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

### The Situation

I have a monitor on my desk that is my daily driver. In another room, i have another monitor which i want to use next to my drumkit for recording purposes. Both monitors are plugged in but i only use my main one since i am sat at my desk.

### The Question

When i am in my studio, is it possible to switch the input from my desk monitor to my studio monitor? For example, is there a piece of hardware i need? Or, is there a certain software that i can use? All suggestions are greatly appreciated!

For what it's worth, i'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

If all else fails, i will need to buy a laptop. But i'm hoping their is a solution to this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the resolution the same on both monitors?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, both monitors are 1440p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both monitors are connected to the PC at all times and both monitors are the same resolution, you can just set them to mirrored at all times and switch on/off the monitors as required.

If that’s not an option for whatever reason you’ll have to switch before leaving, for example using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Or you can try switching blindly, if you’re up for a challenge. :-)

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what i need. If you could show me how to set them to mirrored, i will mark this as the answer.

Comment: That’s also possible using Win+P or just use Display settings.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!